# Typescript throws "Property propName does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<Props>'."

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```js
type PropsWithoutButton = { prop1: any };

type PropsWithButton = PropsWithoutButton & {
  showButton: boolean;
  onButtonPress: () => void;
}

type Props = PropsWithoutButton | PropsWithButton
```

Whenever trying to access `showButton` Typescript is throwing
`Property 'showButton' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<Props>'.`

for example in a React component

```js
const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
  prop1,
  showButton,
  onButtonPress,
}) => ...
```

What's the error here and how can it be solved?

Comment: Is the error at compile time or runtime?

Comment: @RobertRendell at compile time

Comment: An object of type `Props` can be either "WithoutButton" or "WithButton" ... so it may actually not have `showButton` property. If you need `showButton` it means you need to have `React.RC<PropsWithButton>`

Comment: @ConnorLow the answer below actually is closer to what I'm looking for, thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will resolve to the narrowest definition of a union (read unions as "or", e.g. `TypeA | TypeB` - *"TypeA or TypeB"*). `Props`, when used as a function parameter or class property, will resolve to `{ prop1: any }` because `tsc` doesn't know what the real-time value passed to your component will be (i.e. if you pass something of type `PropsWithoutButton`, then `showButton` indeed does not exist).

#### Solutions

You may want something closer to this:

```
type Props = PropsWithoutButton & Partial<PropsWithButton>;
```

Note that this will make both additional props in `PropsWithButton` optional. If you want all or nothing you can use a function to assert a type (a.k.a. type guard):

```
function hasButton(p: Props) : p is PropsWithButton {
  return 'showButton' in p && 'onButtonPress' in p;
}
```

Alternatively, you can check its type inline using `in`, e.g.

```
function bar(p: Props) {
  if ('onButtonPress' in p) {
    console.log(p.showButton); // no error here!
  }
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwOoEtgAsEFdgBC+wCAdlALxQDeUYiYAjAFxQCGpIUAvgNwBQ-UJFgM0mLEWAlyVeEnHY8hYmSgAyGvyhRkOAO5SZrAEYIEAGwgcBOskbLwIyZKwAUASkoA+KADcEdAATAW5BYWh5FEpRBQwlfAdyAB9YlHjJVVJBAHocqAyoCKgAc1w2OCCoADNcUgBjYHQyZn5ahqa1LDZkJLcwVijkL1YwKHRkNMVM6TVqbSg4CGBcOHIAcj0EQyz18fIx9U11+yynFz30A9DBdsbm8mrzfsGxL3mddGqoN27erP6HneCx09TIyEsEAAdBYECV+lCtjtZqQPLYePwwvw8lAACLoJaNCxcepYCD1ADWNQQcDoDAgcFArTunXIJgqLymwM+3zcJ1ISXOyEuB25OigYNIEKsMLhCKRSTRCzCYSAA) is a working example of this.

Comment: isn't that the same as saying:

```
type Props = {
  prop1: any;
  showButton?: boolean;
  onButtonPress?: () => void;
}
```
I don't want to make them optional I want them to both be required if one is present

Comment: @SirajKakeh does my edit address your issue?

Comment: thanx it does, crazy that I need to write a function for that!